# AWS - Postgres Aurora RDS Cluster & `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, multi-tenant, amazon-aurora

I have an Aurora cluster on which I'm trying to globally disable parallel queries (so that I can safely lean on `SET` for configuration parameters to handle multi-tenant-*edness*...), but don't seem to be able to get AWS to cooperate.

I have both modified an existing parameter group, and tried an entirely new parameter group, both times setting `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0 via the RDS console.

However, once the modification is complete, when I then connect to the database and query this with `SHOW max_parallel_workers_per_gather`, I find that the value is still set to the default of 2.

**Am I doing something wrong?** Is there another way to set this parameter globally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This query should tell you where the setting comes from:

```
SELECT setting, source, sourcefile, sourceline
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name = 'max_parallel_workers_per_gather';
```

Comment: Yep, this shows `source` as `default`. I presume this is more of an AWS issue, since they expose the option but it doesn't seem to be respected!